# Is there a general relation between min (f(x) / g(x)) and min f(x) / max g(x)?

Tags: functions

Intuitively, it seems that

$$
\min \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \geq \frac{\min f(x)}{\max g(x)}
$$

if both $f$ and $g$ are positive-valued functions, but is there a more general relationship? Can one also deduce a similar relationship with the $\min$ and $\max$ reversed?

Comment: I am almost sure there are no other relationships.

Comment: @JeanMarie I see. So this sort of relationship only works for positive-valued functions?

Comment: +1 to this posting, despite the posting not actually *showing work*.  For one thing, although the posting is focusing on a purely mathematical question, in my opinion, this is not the sort of question for which it is reasonable to expect that work is shown.  As a second point, this is actually a very relevant question when (for example) constructing an $~\epsilon,\delta~$ proof that $~\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L > 0 ~: ~0 < f(a),g(a),~$ where $~f(x),g(x)~$ are continuous functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make the l.h.s. arbitrarily large compared to the r.h.s., so you won't be able to improve that inequality.

For simplicity, we restrict ourselves to a domain consisting of only two elements: $x\in\{0, 1\}$. Define
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}1,\quad\text{for } x=0,\\X,\quad\text{for } x=1,\\\end{cases},$$
and
$$g(x) = \begin{cases}1/X,\quad\text{for } x=0,\\1,\quad\text{for } x=1,\\\end{cases},$$
where $X>1$ is some parameter.
Then $f/g = X$ always, and can be made arbitrarily large by chosing $X$ large, but
$$\frac{\min f}{\max g}= 1.$$

*Comment*: There is an analogous statement for the maximum:
$$\max\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \le \frac{\max f(x)}{\min g(x)},$$
provided that $f,g\ge 0$ and $\min g > 0$.

Comment: When equality hold.